# Was Greenpeace ever sponsored by the KGB?

Tags: history, environment, soviet-union, kgb

As an urban legend, I've heard this claim  many times. Allegedly, in the 1970s, the [KGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) sponsored various Western "anti-war" movements, especially the ones that could hinder Western nuclear tests. As a matter of fact, [Greenpeace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenpeace) was one such movement, [created in response to nuclear testing in Alaska](http://www.greenpeace.org/usa/en/campaigns/history/), which allegedly earned them the help of the KGB. Quite vague claims. However, recently, I've seen political discussion where more concrete claims were made. Allegedly, the original [Rainbow Warrior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Warrior_(1955)), after being bought by Greenpeace, was refurbished in a shipyard in Tallinn at the KGB's expense. Allegedly, the information comes from the [Mitrokhin Archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitrokhin_Archive).

Is there any truth to any of these claims?

Comment: "Sponsered" seems like a funny word to use here---I'm envisioning a gaudy KGB logo on the bow of the ship---should we take this to mean that the KGB gave substantial amounts of money to Greenpeace with the knowledge of the people running the organization? Is there a better way to say that?

Comment: @dmckee: I believe "sponsored" to be the correct term to use here. Compare for example with usage as in ["State-sponsored terrorism"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-sponsored_terrorism).

Comment: @dmckee - "sponsor: a **person or an organization that pays for** or plans and carries out a project or activity". ([M.-W.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sponsor)) . Sponsorship needs not be for advertising purposes, though it  frequently is.

Comment: I'm having trouble locating a notable claim for the Tallinn refit.

Comment: @DJClayworth: claims by right wing supporters in various forums in Poland. I wouldn't consider it notable, if it wasn't for multiple times it was mentioned.

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: @DJClayworth: for example http://goo.gl/G9jdp http://goo.gl/RL2Xl

Comment: It would be quite surprising if there wasn't some KGB money involved--doesn't mean Greenpeace knew it was Russian money.  Funding Greenpeace would be something consistent with how Russia operated.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Really? It would seem somewhat counterintuitive given that [Greenpeace's first anti-whaling campaign](https://media.greenpeace.org/archive/Soviet-Whaling-Action-27MZIF255II5.html) was carried out in opposition to a Soviet whaling vessel.  [The Soviets killed a lot of whales.](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2022/06/history-of-soviet-whaling-greenpeace-twentieth-century.html): "Though Greenpeace was not the only organization protesting commercial whaling at the time, its campaign against the Soviets had the single greatest impact on the growing movement to save the whales."

Comment: @JimmyJames They caused more headaches for us than for Russia.

Comment: In *Next Stop Execution* Oleg Gordievsky described the KGB system. KGB diplomats would meet anyone with a public profile they classified as "progressive" and offer encouragement and money in exchange for keeping up the good work. This wasn't a well-managed thing: KGB = Dilbert with the death penalty. KGB officers were expected to show they were doing work, and this was work, so it got done. Greenpeace was a high profile org that the KGB would consider "progressive". So it would be surprising if someone didn't show up proffering money.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's impossible to prove that no money from the KGB, or any other source, ever reached Greenpeace (and if it did it might have been without the knowledge of Greenpeace). However we can answer the specific question about the Rainbow Warrior's conversion

Rainbow Warrior (formerly 'Sir William Hardy) [was acquired by Greenpeace in 1977 and refitted in London.](http://www.socialphy.com/posts/off-topic/11993/The-Rainbow-Warrior.html) (See also [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=0wq9fFBP0X4C&pg=PA319&lpg=PA319&dq=%22rainbow%20warrior%22%201977%20refit%20london&source=bl&ots=6NgPi05Mb_&sig=rpuOQKysdmPbfEwldkVnHPUkfig&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2vcvUbjyJOaBywH7lYHACw&sqi=2&ved=0CGQQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22rainbow%20warrior%22%201977%20refit%20london&f=false) and [here](http://www.greenpeace.org/international/en/about/ships/the-rainbow-warrior/rainbow-warrior-I/))

Comment: is www.socialphy.com (or a book citing an unknown source) considered reliable evidence?

Comment: Not the most reliable source I've ever seen, but certainly more reliable than the original claim.

Comment: "More reliable than the original [claimant]" is a low bar to be setting.

Comment: True, original claim isn't reliable. OTOH, what I'd considered really reliable concerning the ship, would be some kind of official ship registry, which would mention where it was build and where it was refitted.

Comment: The [wikipedia article on the ship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_Warrior_%281955%29) points to http://www.greenpeace.org/international/about/ships/the-rainbow-warrior which leads to http://www.greenpeace.org/international/en/about/ships/the-rainbow-warrior/rainbow-warrior-I/.

Comment: How is Greenpeace's own statements in any way reliable as evidence when they have every interest to lie about this? They didn't post any fincncial documents showing the exact budget and how repairs were paid for.

Comment: Well the first paragraph is merely your unsubstantiated opinion, but you should say so instead of assessing something you can't prove. "It's impossible". Not really.

Comment: I said nothing about how the refit was paid for. I am addressing the claim was that it was done in Tallinn.

Answer (score 2):

1. USSR state recording company *Melodia* helped Greenpeace raise money via co-sponsoring a jointly release album (U2 et al).

   http://www.musicstack.com/item/206504892 /
   http://music70-80.narod.ru/katalog/sbor/greenpeace.htm

   While there's no explicit mention of KGB, given the timeline, and the way USSR worked, it was 100% impossible that KGB wasn't in full explicit approval.

   The album was heavily promoted (I remember that myself), and Soviet press was quoted in 1989: “Everyone who buys the album can consider himself a member of Greenpeace, which means it will soon have millions of new members here in the Soviet Union.”

   Quoting from Russian Wiki (*all quotes from that are sourced from Greenpeace itself - " [История Гринпис](http://www.greenpeace.org/russia/ru/about/history/)  (рус.). Greanpease.org. Архивировано из первоисточника 3 февраля 2012. Проверено 13 мая 2011*):

   > В СССР Гринпис появился в 1989 году благодаря средствам от продажи альбома «Гринпис. Прорыв» (Greenpeace Breakthrough). В его записи участвовали U2, Eurythmics, R.E.M., INXS, Шаде, Брайан Ферри и другие рок-звезды.[8]
   >
   > Альбом во всём мире вышел тиражом около 10 миллионов экземпляров, очередь за пластинкой в Москве вошла в книгу рекордов Гиннесса. В течение первых часов с момента выхода пластинки было продано полмиллиона экземпляров. К 15 мая 1989 года общее количество проданных альбомов достигло миллиона.
2. Again from Russian Wiki (same source):

   > В июле 1989 года на пресс-конференции на борту корабля Гринпис «Воин радуги» Алексей Яблоков (в то время председатель комитета по охране окружающей среды СССР), официально объявил отделение Гринпис в СССР «первой независимой организацией в Советском Союзе»
   >
   > In July 1989, during press conference on board "Rainbow Warrior" shop, Alexej Yablokov (President of USSR State Committee for Preservation of the Environment) declared Greenpeace the "first independent organization in USSR".

   Again, given that it was 1989, this was fully State approved and like any interface with the foreigners, fully curated by KGB.

Comment: @DJClayworth - Intelligence reports produced by [Hilaire du Berrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilaire_du_Berrier), former OSS agent and later journalist. I searched but the letters aren't available on the web as far as I'm aware of.

Comment: You also write "given that it was 1989, this was ... fully curated by KGB". 1989 was just one year before the collapse of the Soviet Union and the period of Glasnost and Perestroika.

Comment: @DJClayworth - so? KGB wasn't exactly retired in 1989. All foreign contact were still only with their express OK (having had a foreign contact - as it happens, in 1989 - I can attest to that - though the contact was purely academic, and between schoolkids, and inside USSR).

Comment: @DJClayworth - First of all, if you didn't notice, you are arguing over a miniscule 3rd-in-importance portion of the answers. Second, H. du B. reports aren't John Birch. Guilt by association isn't basis of a proof that information is wrong.

Comment: @DJClayworth - I'll dig further on Pereira, but it'd help if his name wasn't John Smith :(

Comment: And the only source for the first two is your personal opinion.

Comment: @DJClayworth - um... you mean Wikipedia article sourced from Greenpeace's own document, right?

Comment: "given the timeline, and the way USSR worked, it was 100% impossible that KGB wasn't in full explicit approval" I think this is the line that needs supporting the most. It may be true, but it isn't enough to say there was a conspiracy. You need some evidence.

Comment: @Oddthinking - What exactly is the proof that would satisfy you? KGB was always involved in such things, it's not like there would have been some special document that KGB discussed this or that with this specific guy. It was routine.

Comment: @DVK: That's a good question; not sure I have a good answer for you. I am completely ignorant of the KGB's influence on the recording industry at the time. So far, all I have is your word for it. Have their been exposé  documentaries or memoirs published in the past 20 years?

Comment: @Oddthinking - It wasn't the fact that it was recording industry, it was the fact that it was involvment with foreigners.

Comment: Seems to have weak sources... as the others have said.

Comment: @Sklivvz - the source is **Greenpeace's own web site in Russian** admitting dealings with USSR government.

Comment: Ah, but you also said that you didn't consider Greenpeace to be a reliable source :-)

Comment: @DJClayworth - obviously Greenpeace is a lot more reliable source when it comes to facts that paint them in **negative** light (such as being sponsored by USSR) than to facts which paint them in positive light. Just like you would believe a confession from a man that he stole money in his memoirs, whereas you would be a lot more skeptical if he said he didn't (and is a suspect) - he has great motivation to lie in latter case and no great motivation to lie in the former. Neither one is guaranteed to be true, but the former is a lot likelier to be true.

Comment: @DJClayworth See Oddthinking's comment [here](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10618/did-lance-armstrong-use-epo#comment53396_14659) where he noted we regard Armstrong as more reliable when saying he took drugs than when he said he didn't.

Comment: -1 "it was 100% impossible that KGB wasn't in full explicit approval." Quite the logical leap.

Comment: @Schwern - just because you have no first clue how things worked in USSR, doesn't mean it's a "logical leap".

Comment: @user5341 The whole answer hangs on that assumption. This is a Q&A site. The reader may not have all the context you do. Your answer should provide the necessary information and context for the reader (or point to good references). And without it, nobody can check your assumptions. Fill the gap to educate the reader, and so it can be checked.