# Was the KGB using leftists to "destabilize" nations?

Tags: politics, soviet-union, kgb

In 1984, a former KGB agent, [Yuri Bezmenov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuri_Bezmenov), claimed in a [lengthy interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3qkf3bajd4) that:

> [@32:11](https://youtu.be/y3qkf3bajd4?t=32m11s):  [...] progressive intellectuals; writers, journalists, publishers, professors of colleges [...] For us they were just a bunch of political prostitutes to be taken advantage for various propaganda operations.

which he describes multiple times as "useful idiots". For example, about a professor of political science in Delhi University:

> [@48:53](https://youtu.be/y3qkf3bajd4?t=48m53s):  He is made to believe he is invited into USSR because he is a talented, sober thinking intellectual. Absolutely false, he is invited because he is a useful idiot, because [...] when he is coming back to his own country he is going for years and years to teach the beauties of soviet socialism [...] thus promoting the soviet propaganda lie.

According to Bezmenov, there are 4 stages:

1. The "useful idiots" start occupying positions of power and "demoralize" a nation:

   > [@1:09:43](https://youtu.be/y3qkf3bajd4?t=1h9m43s):  Marxism, Leninism ideology is being pumped into the soft heads of at least 3 generations of American students without being challenged [...]. The result: [...] drop-outs or half-baked intellectuals are now occupying positions of power in government, civil service, educational system
2. "Destabilization" follows by attacking/destabilizing:

   > [@1:13:50](https://youtu.be/y3qkf3bajd4?t=1h13m50s):  [...] economy, foreign relations, defense systems.
3. Then follows what he calls "crisis":

   > [@1:14:38](https://youtu.be/y3qkf3bajd4?t=1h14m38s):  a violent change of structure, power and economy
4. "Normalization".

In [another interview](https://youtu.be/pzeHpf3OYQY?t=2h20m3s) where Bezmenov describes the stages in detail, he refers to the key contributors as leftists that should be stopped before the situation escalates into the crisis stage:

> Why didn't you stop the process here [points at demoralization stage], when Grenada was just approached by leftists

---

## Question:

**Was KGB really using leftists in an attempt to damage** nations in the ways described by Yuri Bezmenov?

---

**Note 1:** He uses the term "progressive", "liberals", "leftists"  several times throughout his speeches. I can't post a single quote because Yuri Bezmenov's "claim" is very fragmented.

**Note 2:** I'm not interested in discussing politics, whether communism is good or bad, whether the attack described by Yuri would succeed or not, or its flaws. I'm looking for evidence (preferably official documents, not newspapers) that discredits (or, however unlikely, confirms) the above conspiracy-looking theory.

Comment: a comment on the note: that is better suited for a quick conversation in chat or a question on meta. asking meta questions in the foot of a question on the main site is poor form (as it leads to lengthy discussions in the comments)

Comment: Ok, but how do I phrase it so that readers don't get the wrong impression that i endorse the professor's claims?

Comment: I suggested an edit, feel free to modify it. :) also, here is quite common to ask questions on claims we hear about, but this does not mean we endorse them.

Comment: Ok,if i do something wrong, let me know. Thanks for the tips so far. :)

Comment: Maybe change the phrase *as a means to cause harm* to *in an attempt to cause harm*? Unless thats what Bezmenov literally says?

Comment: @JanDoggen those were not his _exact_ words (it's hard to extract an exact "full" quote, that's why I resorted to multiple quotes). But if your suggestion is more correct grammatically I ll change it.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't try to present a claim as though you endorse it or not.  Adding additional content to advertise your personal beliefs doesn't help anyone and may detract from objectivity.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15179/was-greenpeace-ever-sponsored-by-kgb

Comment: You'd be surprised how much havoc a dissenting opinion can cause, no matter what they believe.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm promoting left-leaning academics/intellectuals etc, is not the same as  promoting anti-war movements. This is definitely not a duplicate. Perhaps not even related. I mean, what's the relation between making a state inefficient (as KGB aligedly did in my question), and "funding" anti-war NGOs? Their only common part is that KGB might have been involved.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Also, please let me know what I can do better in my question. I tried as hard to research, i watched that 1hour long vid twice doing the quotes. Did you downvote because you consider this a useless question? If so, it's ok I guess. I can't do much to improve it (although I d disagree since that guy seems to have affected quite a few people at his university; also we are talking about nearly 1 million views in all vids combined). But if you find anything I can improve, please tell me so that I can make it a good question.

Comment: The way you phrase the question it sounds as if the claim is that marxism/leninism - I don't think Bezmenov used the word "liberal" - was only a tool for the KGB to reach the goal of destabilizing countries. But the context around your quotes sounds like he is saying that the KGB is using marxist propaganda to destabilize countries in an attempt to turn them stalinist (but not with the primary goal of just causing harm; it's just that Bezmenov sees stalinism as harmful). Phrased that way, it doesn't sound as much as a nonsense conspiracy theory, but like a biased summary of soviet propaganda.

Comment: It would definitely help if you could add timestamps for all quotes and possibly a bit more context for them as well. It would also be good to make it very clear what the claim in question actually is (that [the KGB?] invited professors? In the hope that they would adopt a stalinist ideology? Which they would in turn teach their students, leading to a violent change of structure, power and the economy (resulting in an adoption of stalinism)?).

Comment: @tim Thanks so much.  I ll try to make it more clear. And will add the timestamps on the last 2 quotes. The problem with Bezmenov's "claim" is that it is fragmented which makes it hard for anyone to verify that what I say in my question is truly his statements, unless said person watches the whole video.

Comment: @tim I found references to where he calls them "leftists". He uses various terms, including "left", "leftist", "progressive", "liberals". I also took your advice on making it more clear what he claims. I hope now it's much more clear. The problem is that i m trying to summarize 3-hour long interviews into few quotes; pretty much describing a 3 dimensional cube in 2 dimensions :P But hopefully i made it clearer now. If it needs any more improvement, do let me know. And thanks again :)

Comment: Formatted this question a bit.  In the part about 4 stages, it seems like only 3 of them were listed.

Comment: To clarify, the original post had the third stage explicitly labeled as Stage 3, so presumably it's Stage 4 that's missing.

Comment: @Nat the 4th stage (Normalization) is described seconds after stage 3. I guess no one watched the full interview :P I didn't include it to make the question more succinct, but since you wanted to number them, i guess you should edit 4th stage in, as well.

Answer (score 18):

These kinds of claims did not originate with Yuri Bezmenov, and he is not claiming some kind of scoop. For example, the phrase "useful idiot" was not popularized by *anyone* in Russia but by [anti-communist writers in the United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useful_idiot). Another famous person who claimed that Russians found Americans easy to manipulate was the *Gulag Archipelago* author Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn, who [argued that](http://www.lib.ru/PROZA/SOLZHENICYN/s_word_engl.txt_with-big-pictures.html) virtually all attempts to negotiate with Communists expected good faith that the other side didn't have:

> I would like to call upon America to be more careful with its trust and prevent those wise persons who are attempting to establish even finer degrees of justice and even finer legal shades of equality - some because of their distorted outlook, others because of short-sightedness and still others out of selfinterest - from falsely using the struggle for peace and for social justice to lead you down a false road. Because they are trying to weaken you; they are trying to disarm your strong and magnificent country in the face of this fearful threat - one which has never been seen before in the history of the world.

Solzhenitsyn's speech is worth reading, because he expressed what both of these defectors were worried about with a bit more nuance and depth. It's not that American leftists propagate Russian lies per se, but rather that American leftism is frequently anarchist, anti-hierarchy, and anti-violence, and that  from the perspective of Russian leftism, which stresses "dictatorship of the proletariat," this comes off as utter *naïveté*, which can be manipulated not merely to "spread lies" but also to directly gain the upper hand in diplomacy.

I now return to Bezmenov's claim that leftists are brainwashed by crafty Russians to "teach the beauties of Soviet socialism". This was an oversimplification on his part. (I reiterate that I think he was trying to say what Solzhenitsyn actually said.) It has a grain of truth to it but is not a correct generalization.

It's true that to some extent Russian propaganda can be shown to have an influence over those with socialist tendencies abroad. For example, the [Communist Party USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_USA) and [Japanese Communist Party](https://www.wsws.org/en/articles/2009/08/japa-a28.html), to name two examples, were both Stalinist right up to [Khrushchev's secret speech](https://www.britannica.com/event/Khrushchevs-secret-speech) in 1956. They both propagated Russian-invented lies about Stalin's purges and the Holodomor.

Plenty of examples of similar naive acceptance can be found, [including](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potemkin_village#Examples_of_Potemkin_villages):

> - Western visitors to the Soviet Union were strictly controlled by the secret police, especially during the Soviet famine of 1932–33, e.g. [Édouard Herriot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Herriot) [**French Prime Minister** at that time] said that Soviet Ukraine was "like a garden in full bloom".
> - [Henry A. Wallace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_A._Wallace) [**United States Vice President** at that time] visited a Soviet slave labor camp in Magadan in 1944 and believed that the prisoners were *volunteers*.

There were also plenty of reporters who [collaborated](http://www.holodomorct.org/HOLODOMOR-WORLD%20REACTION-PROPAGANDA-MEDIA.html) with Stalin's cover-up of the Holodomor.

So, there is some basis to Bezmenov's claim.

However, the truth got out about Soviet Communism from a very early stage on the American left. There were plenty of leftists who showed that they were not naive at all, at least in their ability to doubt Stalinist propaganda. These dissenters were already massive in the 1920s and eventually created the [Fourth International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_International) as a direct confrontation to Stalin.

Responses to the Fourth International created a strong, critical intellectual climate that spawned journals like the *[New Left Review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Left_Review)* and *[Dissent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissent_(American_magazine))*. This intellectual crowd was very familiar with the Soviets and very critical and skeptical of them. It is unfair to characterize them as Bezmenov did.

There were also plenty of Westerners who [exposed](https://townhall.com/columnists/marygrabar/2013/07/23/larry-grathwohl-1947-2013-american-hero-n1647239) various propaganda operations:

> Victor Kravchenko, Gareth Jones, George H. Earle, William Bullit, John C. Wiley, Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn, Whittaker Chambers, Elia Kazan, Major George Racey Jordan, John Van Vliet, and Ivan Krivosertsov, the last a Russian peasant who witnessed and told about the execution of Polish officers in the Katyn forest by the Soviets, but was found dead, mysteriously, some years later in England.

All of their reports faced opposition from some leftists but have eventually been integrated into mainstream history.

Claiming that Western leftists, as a whole, were simple dupes of the Soviets is a distortion of history that removes agency from the Westerners in question.

Comment: I don't think Bezmenov claims that **all** leftists were in agreement with USSR. What I m guessing he means is that some leftists could be used to gradually make a nation inefficient, dysfunctional, and utterly unstable. That doesn't require a large portion of the population to be directly manipulated by KGB. The KGB was aiming mainly at "progressive" people of power/influence with the purpose of creating more left-leaning people (professors brainwashing their students, some of which would later become leftist-professors etc). [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] I'm sure some leftists spotted the propaganda by the USSR but were they enough to stop it? Also, although they might have spotted Stalin's crime-washing propaganda, Bezmenov is probably referring to communism-inspired "values" as the true weapon (which supposedly causes inefficiency, dysfunction etc). Other than that, I think your answer was very interesting to read and useful :) But I m afraid I cannot accept it in its current state.

Comment: "Bezmenov is probably referring to communism-inspired "values" as the true weapon (which supposedly causes inefficiency, dysfunction etc). " So what is your actual question, then? Whether Russia was itself a dysfunctional country that was purposefully trying to export that dysfunction to the west? I'm not sure a neutral answer to that is possible. I think politics.SE may be a better forum for that question.

Comment: _"[..] Russia was itself a dysfunctional country that was purposefully trying to export that dysfunction"_ - I'm not asking that (and it's questionable if USSR was as dysfunctional as the target-countries; also there are many benefits from having target-countries being controlled by the "mother-country" of communism, but this is rather off-topic here). My question is: Did KGB use (that is: promote, influence, take advantage of, feed with propaganda) leftists of power/influence in order to cause "destabilization" as defined [here](https://youtu.be/pzeHpf3OYQY?t=2h6m23s)

Comment: It's hard to include every single of his quotes, because of the fragmentation of his speeches. I would have to isolate words, phrases, and post lots of tiny quotes, and the question will turn into a mess.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, then. Bezmenov talked about people who are "invited into [the] USSR," and claimed that these people become "useful idiots." I tried to answer that specific claim because for that one, you can show lots of evidence. His grander conspiracy theory is too generic to disprove. Like, for comparison, did Bush "use" the "conservative media" to promote his view of the Iraq War? That lumps together Fox News with The American Conservative (anti-war magazine) etc. and is either trivially false or so generic it's meaningless.

Comment: I disagree it can't be proved. For example leaked official documents with the "graph" at https://youtu.be/pzeHpf3OYQY?t=2h7m53s would be more than enough to prove that KGB-promoted leftists with the purpose to "demoralize", "destabilize" and cause a "crisis" (as those words are defined in the question). About disproving this wild theory, multiple inconsistencies or lies in what Bezmenov says would be a good hint. Or again (preferably) leaked documents suggesting he was not a spy, but rather a nutjob that borrowed his theory from X place during Y time. There are many ways it can be disproved.

Comment: If my question is unclear, how should I phrase it? Perhaps instead of _"Was KGB really using leftists in an attempt to damage nations in the ways described by Yuri Bezmenov?"_ i should ask: _"Was KGB really using (that is: promoting, influencing, feeding with communist propaganda, taking advantage of) leftists in an attempt to damage nations in the ways described by Yuri Bezmenov?"_. Would that make it clear? If not, tips would be quite welcome :) I d love to avoid confusion of reader.

Comment: Alas, I have no interest in watching the entire video to catch contractions, and I'm not sure what kind of contradictions would meet your standards anyway. I don't think your proposed rephrasing makes sense, either.

Comment: @Avery: You're missing  Bezmenov's point! He absolutely didn't imply the brainwashing was to create belief Soviet Union was all sunshine&rainbows! Its goal was to destroy the US elites by filling them with people of a completely useless mindset that neglects strategic issues, removes competent people from positions of influence and creates so much of internal conflict that USA becomes powerless against a military aggression. It doesn't matter the engineered mindset happens to incorporate many Marxist ideas. It's not about accepting USSR or communism, it's about making USA internally weak!

Comment: ...never mind reaching for examples nearly a century old misses the entire point - it's the current generation of academic teachers who are supposed to be the actual successfully built network of unwitting "brainwashers", and the current, and most recent generations of students to be the first wave that is to occupy the positions of influence, replacing neutral competence metrics with enforced racial and gender parity for professional positions. And the whole Neonazi-Antifa riots are exactly the kind of instability the program wanted to achieve.

Comment: @SF. I literally said that in the first paragraph of my answer, and pointed to Solzhenitsyn's clearer restatement of the same argument. I have no idea why you wrote this comment.

Comment: I guess you might be one of these unfortunate people like Bezmenov who can't tell the difference between naïveté and being "brainwashed".

Comment: @Avery: Your summary is "Claiming that Western leftists, as a whole, were simple dupes of the Soviets is a distortion of history that removes agency from the Westerners in question." Nowhere do the sources, or the question imply "leftists *as a whole*" so restricting your conclusions to that qualifier simply doesn't address the matter. The fact many leftists oppose the radicals, is just another internal conflict (as intended).

Comment: @Avery: If the "social justice" mindset (as defined by Bezmenov) is accepted by *a large fraction* (not ALL!) of leftists in positions of power   then the *alleged* goals of KGB (as defined by Bezmenov) are met. Whether the prevalence of that mindset is mere result of naïveté or purposeful brainwashing, that is the very gist of the question. The alleged goals as stated by Bezmenov, are currently met, that's an indisputable fact. The only question remains: Was this KGB's doing, or did it happen "all by itself" for other reasons?

Comment: Your answer boils down to "Majority in USA resisted known instances of KGB's meddling". True but irrelevant. IF the answer is "Yes, KGB was doing it", then your statement would boil down to "KGB lost battles but won the war", considering the current political landscape fits Bezmenov's predictions. If not - if it was pure naïveté and not brainwashing - we're still at the same point, only without effort on KGB's side.

Comment: Okay, your third comment confirms that my assumption in my second comment was correct. You are literally unable to distinguish between naïveté and "brainwashing". I suggest reading one of those books that you seem to fear might be filled with Soviet impurities? Agent Judith Butler awaits your orders.

Comment: I will add that even three years later I still don't understand the point of SF's comments. What exactly did he believe the KGB was doing? Did the KGB sponsor Jim Crow and engender the civil rights movement? It's a true mystery

Comment: A small factual mistake : Édouard Herriot was not France's Prime Minister anymore when he visited Ukraine between in August and September 1933. He had resigned from office on 18 December 1932. The Prime Minister during Herriot's trip was Édouard Daladier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Daladier

Answer (score 7):

Oleg Gordievsky was a KGB colonel who spied for the British. In his autobiography "Next stop execution" he writes about his work with "agents of influence" and "confidential contacts of influence".

> These were likely to be people whose political inclinations might make them sympathetic to some aspect of the Soviet view of the world; many were idealists, and most "gave" their help unwitingly.

[...]

> "Contacts" did not usually know they were being pursued, or that the "press atache" [...] buying them a drink or a meal was in fact a KGB officer. Many would have been horrified if anyone suggested they were actively "helping" the adversary.

Gordievsky then relates his contacts with a wide range of characters in the British left at the time.

> "My conclusion is that if the Labour Party had been returned to power in June 1983 the KGB would have been in a strong position. [...] With Labour in power the KGB would have been able to pick up a great deal of information about what was going on within the British government.

As well as cultivating possible sources of information the KGB also tried to create positive publicity for the USSR. However this was much less successful. One exercise described by Gordievsky involved a group of sympathetic journalists from The Guardian being taken on a tour of the USSR. However the resulting coverage was so tepid that the KGB officer who had organised it had to fend off accusations of incompetence.

Comment: _"However this was much less successful."_ - Besides the failed Guardian tour, are there other evidence or hints that this is the case? I don't mean isolated cases where positive publicity failed.

Comment: @MariaBl. The relevant chapter has a number of anecdotes of a similar kind. The Communist Party was subsidized, but to no effect. One of Gordievsky's clandestine contacts was Ron Brown, but his Scottish accent was so thick that Gordievsky couldn't understand him. Brown backed the Sovient regime in Afganistan, which the Kremlin counted as a success, but in reality this merely made him a target of ridicule in the UK. Gordievsky doesn't draw specific conclusions, but the whole tenor of his memoir is that the KGB was Dilbert with the death penalty.

Answer (score 0):

This was pretty much the "common soviet narrative".
Like "*Americans know that the US is the best country in the world*" and "*Muslims consider all infidels worthy of death*", "*Soviet people know that USSR supports all the leftist movements in the world, as it should*" (either covertly or overtly). <sup><sub>/of course, not everyone thinks that way, but "most" do/</sub></sup>

One way observable to me in Moscow was that, apparently, the whole print of the ["Morning Star"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morning_Star_(British_newspaper)) was distributed in the USSR:

> Soviet bulk orders ended abruptly in 1989, and the termination of this order, with very little notice, was the cause of "huge financial disruption".

More wonderful examples come from the [Bazhanov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Bazhanov)'s [memoir](http://lib.ru/MEMUARY/BAZHANOW/stalin.txt), one of them is translated in [Foreign Investment and Lena Goldfields](https://ickmansblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/foreign-investment-and-lena-goldfields.html); here is the punchline, one should read the whole thing:

> [Bukharin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Bukharin): “the most remarkable thing is that these cretins in the Labor party have taken our arguments at face value…I propose that we send Comrade [MacDonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsay_MacDonald) to be secretary of the Party committee in [Kyshtym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyshtym), and appoint [M. Tomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Tomsky) prime minister in London.”